# Python фильтрация слов

Tags: python, фильтрация

Хочу сделать программу которая фильтрует строковый список

Допустим

```
list = ['арбуз', 'паприка', 'дерево', 'хор', 'дверь', 'ор', 'приз', 'свет']
```

Мне известно что в слове 6 букв и знаю буквы 'е' и 'в'
По итогу программа должна мне выдать 'дерево'(исходя из этого списка слов)

То что у меня есть

```
list = ['арбуз', 'паприка', 'дерево', 'хор', 'дверь', 'ор', 'приз', 'свет']
```

> #это список для примера, основной  список из более 5000 слов

```
word = input('Введите буквы которые  вам известны')    
length = int(input('Введите длину слова'))

for line in list:
   if len(line) == lenght:
      print(line)
```

Comment: непонятно, зачем здесь сортировка? Как вы пытались решить эту проблему? Что у вас уже есть?

Comment: Так сортировать список или выдать слово? Сортировать список - sort(). По количеству букв?

Comment: Не, ну догадаться можно, что человек хочет. Но опять же это элементарная ведь задача. Одно не пойму - почему все фильтрацию называют сортировкой? Впрочем, я уже, кажется, спрашивал...

Comment: Так, уже хорошо. Проверять вхождение одной буквы в слово умеете? Про оператор `in` знаете? Осталось догадаться, как проверить тоже самое в цикле с буквами из списка.

Comment: list зарезервированное слово в Пайтоне

Comment: В том то и дело что дальше ничего не работает у меня. Я понимаю что это полевая программа, но пока в голову ничего не приходит и ответов не нашёл

Comment: @Сергей Ш это только для примера, как уже писал, основной список больше и естественно называется по другому

Comment: if len(line) == lenght? if len(line) == length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Через множества

```
lst = ['арбуз', 'паприка', 'дерево', 'хор', 'дверь', 'ор', 'приз', 'свет']
chars = set(input('Введите буквы, которые вам известны: ').lower())
length = int(input('Введите длину слова: '))

for word in lst:
    if len(word) == length and chars.issubset(word.lower()):
        print(word)
```

Comment: Cпасибо, очень помогли, не думал что решения на столько простое.

Answer (score 1):

```
word = 'и'
length = 4
lst = ['арбуз', 'паприка', 'дерево', 'хор', 'дверь', 'ор', 'приз', 'свет']
print(*filter(lambda x: len(x) == length and word in x, lst), sep='\n')
```